# displaying a progressdialog before a video

Tags: android, video, progressdialog

I am trying to displaying a ProgressDialog before a video with the following code:

```
package com.Boodang;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoLoading extends Activity implements Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoViewDemo";

    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private EditText mPath;
    private ImageView mPlay;
    private ImageView mPause;
    private ImageButton mReset;
    private ImageView mStop;
    private String current;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context mContext;
    String s=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state){

    super.onCreate(state);


    dialog=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Loding.PleaseWait",true);
    Thread t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
       Log.e("VideoPlay1 page","OnStart");
        setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);


        mPlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play);
        mPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pause);

        mStop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    current = null;
                    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                }
            }
        });
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
              dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });


    }
    public void run(){
        Message msg;
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
 Handler handler=new Handler(){
@Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {

            mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
            s=getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

            final String path = s;
            Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
            if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoLoading.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
                if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
                mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error123: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }

    }
 };
    private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
        if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
            return path;
        } else {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
            cn.connect();
            InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
            if (stream == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
            File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
            temp.deleteOnExit();
            String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);


            } while (true);

            try {
                stream.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
               Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            return tempPath;
        }
    }


}
```

but I do not get the progress bar here. all I get is the the video directly.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of dismissing the progress dialog in runOnUiThread, dismiss it in the onPreparedListener:

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

runOnUiThread is called right away, therefore dimissing the dialog before it can be seen. This code will keep it going until the video is ready to start.

Comment: You helped me..Thanks a lot...was  trying to figure out why the progress dialog was not visible.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an AsyncTask to do that. have a look on [this page](http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask). it gives you detailed information on how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to move away from the synchronous `MediaPlayer` calls to do this.  The [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) has  series of player state change callbacks such as [onPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29) which you'll need to make use of to determine when to display your dialog.

What you are experiencing is due to the fact that, although you are putting work to the uiThread, you are basically putting all your work to the uiThread.

The call:

```
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
```

is going on the uiThread (seemingly).  You need to use the async listeners to avoid having to build those facilities for yourself.